# How can I get the Fully Qualified type of an Argument in an ArgumentList?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to write a utility for our development team that will generate unit tests to enforce, at a minimum, code coverage. I'm using Roslyn to inspect the code they have written in order to generate stubs for things like DB access.

For example, I have the following function I am trying to generate a unit test for:

```
public DiaryDro GetDiaryById(long id)
{
    return Translator.EntityToDro(_repository.FindOne<Diary>(id));
}
```

I can find and use everything I need, including mocking our Repository as it is a class level variable so that's easy and done. I can also Mock out the Translator, and generate the Stub for EntityToDro. The problem I have is, I have no idea how to tell the arguments that are being passed into the EntityToDro function.

Using Roslyn, I can get to the InvocationExpressionSyntax that has the `return` line in it, and it has a field `ArgumentList`, and I can even muddy my way down to find that it's getting a `Diary`, but  I need the fully qualified name, as we have more than one type of `Diary`.

Is there any way at all to do this, or can I not get there from here?

Answer (score 1):

To get type information, you need to query the semantic model:

```
document.GetSemanticModel().GetTypeInfo(expression)
```